# How to resolve pgrouting dijkstra_sp() function error?

Tags: pgrouting, error

```
insert into dijsktra_results(geom) select ST_UNION(the_geom) from dijkstra_sp('roads_layer',
            (select source_id from roads_layer where gid=9975)::integer,
            (select target_id from roads_layer where gid=2967)::integer);
```

This query to perform the routing operations. 
"dijsktra_results" is a newely created table for routing operations with gid and geom columns of 2D(MultiLineString).
This is the error I am getting

```
ERROR:  column "the_geom" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT gid,the_geom FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid as id, so...
                   ^
QUERY:  SELECT gid,the_geom FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid as id, source::integer, target::integer, length::double precision as cost FROM roads_layer', '1' , '20142' , false, false), roads_layer where edge_id = gid 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "dijkstra_sp" line 13 at FOR over EXECUTE statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "the_geom" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Context: PL/pgSQL function "dijkstra_sp" line 13 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
```

Can anyone resolve this problem or guide for an extent am I gone wrong anywhere.Till now everything worked fine.I calculated vertex_id,edge_id,length....
And how this, dijkstra_sp() function works and calculates the shortest path.

Comment: Hi, I think it would be best to split your questions. One for help resolving this error and another for the djikstra_sp() explanation. That way, it would be easier for people to vote on the answers and to answer your question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added table alias sp and r

```
SELECT r.gid, r.the_geom 
FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid as id, source::integer, target::integer, length::double precision as cost FROM roads_layer', '1' , '20142' , false, false) as sp , roads_layer as r 
WHERE sp.edge_id = r.gid
```

So `r.the_geom` doesn't exist, is it possible that your geometry column name is `geog/geom` and not `the_geom`?